# Language Translation Dictionaries For Tech Terms

Tags: internationalization, translation

I'm creating a web app that I would like to be able to translate into different languages. I realize that hiring a translator is the best option, but some terms may not be in the translator's vocabulary depending on their exposure to the web and technology. The translator may produce a direct translation that does not match the convention used for that term. Are there web/tech-specific language dictionaries available that could supplement a translator that include localized versions of terms like 'email', 'website', 'click', 'save', 'username', etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Proz.com Kudoz](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/) terms dictionary. There you can narrow down your search by specific fields, in this case Computers: Software.

Kudoz Questions are user generated all over the world in most language pairs. It's kinda of StackOverflow but for translation work.

I think Kudoz is a great source for translations.

Comment: No doubt. I have a profile there where I contribute with things I think :) I already know: http://www.proz.com/profile/849397